# Regex remove a first period

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to remove a period prior to the `"@"` symbol from an email. I got:

```
array[0][2].gsub(/\./, '').strip
```

which removes both periods; `"an.email@test.com"` becomes `"anemail@testcom"`, while I'm looking for it to become `"anemail@test.com"`. I can't remove just the single period by itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `array`? If `array[0][2]` is the string relevant to the question, then start with a string assigned to it (with explanation). Don't introduce irrelevant things into the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove ... from email"? Do you mean "remove ... from an email address"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no periods before `@` or if there are more than one period, you can use this regex

```
email = "my.very.long.email@me.com"
email.gsub(/\.(?=[^@]*\@)/, '')
# => "myverylongemail@me.com"
```

**Regex explanation:** period followed by zero or more occurrence of any character other than `@`, followed by an `@`

If only the first occurrence of a period before `@` has to be removed, you can use the same regex with `sub` instead of `gsub`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.gsub(/\.(?=\S+@)/, '')
```

**Explanation**

- `\.` matches a period
- the `(?=\S+@)` lookahead asserts that what follows is any non-whitespace chars followed by an arrobas
- we replace with the empty string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make this more complicated by trying to make it short. Just write it the way you mean it:

```
a, b = address.split('@')
cleaned = [a.delete('.'), b].join('@')
```